# Create a nested table and insert data only in the inner table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have this table: employees(id, firstname, lastname, salary) and I added another column that will store all the past salaries of every employee.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE salary_list AS TABLE OF NUMBER;
/
ALTER TABLE employees
ADD (salary_history salary_list)
NESTED TABLE salary_history STORE AS salary_history_tab;
```

Now, the table is employees(id, firstname, lastname, salary, *salary_history*) and salary_history is null. When I modify the salaray value, **how do I insert the current salary value into the inner table salary_history?** I have tried:

```
INSERT INTO 
TABLE(SELECT salary_history FROM employees WHERE id=1) 
VALUES(1500);
```

And I get the following error:

> ORA-22908: reference to NULL table value

Yes, the nested table salary_history is null because I just created it. What am I doing wrong? What is the correct way to insert values(append to the existing data) into *salary_history* identifying the employee by id?

UPDATE:
added nvl(,()) like so:

```
INSERT INTO 
TABLE(SELECT nvl(salary_history,salary_list()) FROM employees WHERE id=1) 
VALUES(1000);
```

The error that I get now is:

> ORA-25015: cannot perform DML on this nested table view column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `COALESCE( salary_history, salary_list() ) MULTISET UNION ALL salary_list( :your_new_value )` to append the new value to the old list (or create a new list if it does not exist).

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE salary_list AS TABLE OF NUMBER;
/

CREATE TABLE employees(
  id             NUMBER,
  salary_history salary_list
) NESTED TABLE salary_history STORE AS salary_history_tab
/

INSERT INTO employees VALUES ( 1, NULL )
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
UPDATE employees
SET   salary_history = COALESCE( salary_history, salary_list() )
                       MULTISET UNION ALL salary_list( 500 )
WHERE id = 1

SELECT * FROM employees
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/84929c/3/1)**:

```
| ID | SALARY_HISTORY |
|----|----------------|
|  1 |            500 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
UPDATE employees
SET   salary_history = COALESCE( salary_history, salary_list() )
                       MULTISET UNION ALL salary_list( 700 )
WHERE id = 1

SELECT * FROM employees
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/84929c/3/3)**:

```
| ID | SALARY_HISTORY |
|----|----------------|
|  1 |        500,700 |
```

**Query 3**:

```
UPDATE employees
SET   salary_history = COALESCE( salary_history, salary_list() )
                       MULTISET UNION ALL salary_list( 500 )
WHERE id = 1

SELECT * FROM employees
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/84929c/3/5)**:

```
| ID | SALARY_HISTORY |
|----|----------------|
|  1 |    500,700,500 |
```

Answer (score 2):

The column is currently null, rather than an empty table; you can create an empty nested table to start with:

```
UPDATE employees
SET salary_history = NEW salary_list()
WHERE id = 1;

1 row updated.
```

And your first statement will then work:

```
INSERT INTO 
TABLE(SELECT salary_history FROM employees WHERE id=1) 
VALUES(1500);

1 row inserted.
```

You can see the new value:

```
SELECT * FROM employees;

        ID FIRSTNAME  LASTNAME       SALARY SALARY_HISTORY                
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ------------------------------
         1 Joe        BLoggs           1234 SALARY_LIST(1500)
```