# Append to Oracle User-Defined Collection Type

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I want to preserve all inserted rows on object reference variable. But not find any thing how i can do that. Can anyone check my script and correct it.

```
create or replace type "GT_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS" as object (OBJECT_ID number, OBJECT_TYPE varchar2(64));
/
create or replace type "T_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS" as table of "GT_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS";
/
VARIABLE CURS REFCURSOR;
/
DECLARE
   v_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS T_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS;
BEGIN
   --Explicit Constructor
   SELECT GT_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS (10, 'STUDENT')
   BULK   COLLECT INTO v_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS
   FROM   DUAL;

   SELECT GT_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS (11, 'COLLEGE')
   BULK   COLLECT INTO v_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS
   from   DUAL;
   OPEN :curs FOR SELECT * FROM TABLE (v_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS);
end;
/
PRINT :CURS
```

When i execute script. It is displaying final output as

```
OBJECT_ID   OBJECT_TYPE

11          COLLEGE
```

I Need output as

```
OBJECT_ID   OBJECT_TYPE

10          STUDENT
11          COLLEGE
```

How i can pereserve all inserted records

Answer (score 4):

You can do it all in PL/SQL and do not need to context-switch to the SQL scope:

```
DECLARE
   -- Initialise the collection
   v_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS T_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS := T_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS();
BEGIN
   -- Extend the collection by the default amount (1 element)
   v_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS.EXTEND;
   -- Set the first element to be your student type
   v_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS(1) := GT_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS (10, 'STUDENT');

   -- Extend the collection by 1 element
   v_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS.EXTEND(1);
   -- Set the last element to be your college type
   v_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS(v_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS.COUNT) := GT_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS (11, 'COLLEGE');

   OPEN :curs FOR SELECT * FROM TABLE (v_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS);
END;
/
```

You could also do it in the constructor:

```
DECLARE
   -- Initialise the collection
   v_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS T_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS := T_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS(
       GT_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS (10, 'STUDENT'),
       GT_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS (11, 'COLLEGE')
     );
BEGIN
   OPEN :curs FOR SELECT * FROM TABLE (v_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS);
END;
/
```

or, if you want to use SQL then you don't need the collection type if you populate the rows of the cursor directly using `UNION ALL`:

```
BEGIN
   OPEN :curs FOR
     SELECT GT_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS (10, 'STUDENT') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT GT_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS (11, 'COLLEGE') FROM DUAL;
END;
/
```

or, using the collection:

```
BEGIN
   OPEN :curs FOR
     SELECT *
     FROM TABLE(
       T_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS(
         GT_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS (10, 'STUDENT'),
         GT_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS (11, 'COLLEGE')
       )
     );
END;
/
```

then, with either of the previous two versions, you could just avoid cursors and PL/SQL entirely. I.e.:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE(
  T_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS(
    GT_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS (10, 'STUDENT'),
    GT_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS (11, 'COLLEGE')
  )
);
```

or, to [merge two collections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49567264/1509264):

```
DECLARE
  v_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS T_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS;
BEGIN
  --Explicit Constructor
  v_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS := T_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS( GT_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS (10, 'STUDENT') );

  -- Merge in SQL using MUTLISET UNION ALL
  SELECT v_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS
         MULTISET UNION ALL
         T_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS( GT_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS (11, 'COLLEGE') )
  INTO v_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS
  FROM   DUAL;

  OPEN :curs FOR SELECT * FROM TABLE (v_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the first row with the second. Use a single `select` with `UNION ALL` to load it together.

```
SELECT * BULK COLLECT
INTO v_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS
FROM (
    SELECT GT_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS(10, 'STUDENT')
    FROM DUAL  UNION ALL
    SELECT GT_OBJECT_TYPE_REL_IDS(11, 'COLLEGE')
    FROM DUAL
   );
```

Also, if you convert this to a `PIPELINED FUNCTION`, there no need of a `CURSOR` variable. You could simply run `SELECT * FROM TABLE(fn_pipelinedfunc);`